# How can I remove 0s from an array within an INDEX formula?

Tags: excel

I'm writing a bit of a complicated `INDEX` formula here and I'm really close to the solution.

- The `INDEX` below matches the row of the array based on two criteria
  and the column based on a string elsewhere.
- I'm using the `ROW` function to simulate a `MATCH` function to pass to the `INDEX`,
  and `N(IF())` to de-reference the `INDEX` function and pass an array of values to
  the `MIN` function.
- I'm using `ROW` instead of `MATCH` because `MATCH(1,,)` would only return the
  first value of 6 TRUE that result from the two criteria.

It all works except for one issue: the array I pass to `INDEX` after `N(IF(1,ROW()))` still has a bunch of 0s. For example, it gets "{0,0,0,0,22,23,24,0,0)" so `INDEX` passes "{54,54,54,54,87,91,78,54,54}" to the MIN function.

Hence my issue. I feel like I'm really close to the answer but I've gotten stuck. If I could somehow remove the 0s from the array so that only "{22,23,24}" gets passed to `INDEX`, then everything would work in my sheet.

```
=IF($H$9="","",
  MIN(INDEX($A$9:$Z$5000,
    N(IF(1,ROW($A$1:$A$4991)*(M$3=$H$9:$H$5000)*($X$6=$A$9:$A$5000))), 
    MATCH($H4&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&$V$3&CHAR(10)&"(lbs)",$A$8:$Z$8,0))))
```

Comment: One note: since you are using `$A$9:$Z$5000` as your range to index and are returning the row number your data will be off.  Index expects a relative position not the row number.  So if the first row in the area meets your criteria it will return `9` to the index which will return the value located in the 9th row of the range or `A17:Z17`

Comment: good catch! Thanks, fixed the typo in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of building an array just use MIN(IF())

```
=IF($H$9="","",MIN(IF((M$3=$H$9:$H$5000)*($X$6=$A$9:$A$5000)*(INDEX($A$9:$Z$5000,0,MATCH($H4&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&$V$3&CHAR(10)&"(lbs)",$A$8:$Z$8,0))<>0),INDEX($A$9:$Z$5000,0,MATCH($H4&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&$V$3&CHAR(10)&"(lbs)",$A$8:$Z$8,0)))))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting Edit Mode.

---

It is even simpler with Office 365:

```
=IF($H$9="","",MINIFS(INDEX(A:Z,0,MATCH($H4&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&$V$3&CHAR(10)&"(lbs)",$8:$8,0)),INDEX(A:Z,0,MATCH($H4&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&$V$3&CHAR(10)&"(lbs)",$8:$8,0)),"<>0",$H:$H,$M$3,$A:$A,$X$6))
```

Comment: Absolutely incredible, that worked! I spent hours trying to figure that out, thank you so much! 

I was so focused on trying to specify the references for the INDEX function, I didn't think to pass the INDEX as a column and check the criteria outside of it. Much cleaner. Thanks again Scott, you taught me a new trick today.

Comment: hey Scott, looking at the proposed solution again this morning, it works great but I do have a question after watching it evaluate: 

what purpose does the first INDEX()<>0 term serve? It seems to just check that the column of data does not have any 0s in it, is that it?

Comment: The way I read it was you wanted to exclude `0` from the MIN, but now that I reread, you were getting 0 to the INDEX, It can be removed.